# ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea как задать диапазон руками

Tags: vba

Как вместо диапазона "A:I" в примере ниже, реализовать возможность задавать его(диапазон) руками, путём выделения мышью сквозных столбцов нужной области?

```
Sub xxx()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "A:I"
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 100
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для ручного ввода диапазона используем *InputBox*

```
Sub PrintRange()
Dim r As Range
    Set r = Application.InputBox("Выдедить диапазон печати", "ВЫБОР", Type:=8)
    ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = r.Address
'.....................
End Sub
```

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Такой код выбирает для печати выделенную мышкой область

```
Sub xxx()
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Selection.Address
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .CenterHorizontally = True
        .CenterVertically = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = 100
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо большое это именно то, что я и просил, но vikttur предложил более наглядный вариант.

Comment: мне кажется, вы не тот ответ отметили как принятый,и это будет вводить в заблуждение посетителей, ищущих "как задавать диапазон путем выделения мышью"

Comment: Я немного поправил содержание вопроса, чтобы оно соответствовало моему выбору правильного ответа, Вам ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Конечно, вам решать